# Mongo DB and Java ends with Regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to get all documents from my database where the page path ends with a certain expression using this code:

```
query.put(pagepath, new BasicDBObject(
"$regex", "/(" +expression+ ")$/"));
```

and where expression is replaced by values like ".html", ".JSON", "contact/", "/"...
I get no errors but no results either, even though, when I test my regex on https://regex101.com/ it works and one of the links at least matchs.

[image]

Comment: Try `expression + "$"`. Also, you'd need to escape the `.` somehow. So, perhaps, `BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();` and then `query.put(pagepath, Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(expression)+"$"));`

Comment: tanks but It did not work and I have my query looking like this: `{ "\"pagepath\"" : { "$regex" : "\\Q.html\\E$"}}`

Comment: Should the column names be inside literal double quotes? Anyway, the regex seems correct now.

Comment: yep that part is ok (y)

Comment: That query works in https://regex101.com/ but not in Robomongo:

Comment: I have read about that and see that `query.put(pagepath, new BasicDBObject("$regex", Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(expression)+"$")));` should work. If not, I cannot help more :(

Comment: OK thank you :)  I will keep trying.

Comment: Any progress? When you succeed please let know by posting the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the solution : `query.put(pagepath, new BasicDBObject("$regex", ".*(" + expression + ")$"));`

Comment: Ok, that means you need to match the entire string, `matches()` in the background. Still, this is not fully correct approach, because you need to quote the `expression`, else, if it contains special regex metacharacters, you will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that will account for any special characters in the `expression` *and* potential newline symbols in the string is

```
query.put(pagepath, new BasicDBObject("$regex", "(?s).*" + Pattern.quote(expression) + "$"));
```

Four points are:

- You need to match the *entire* string, so you need to use `.*` before the `expression`
- If a string has newlines, you need to pass the `(?s)` DOTALL modifier so that `.` could also match newline symbols
- You need to `Pattern.quote` the `expression` so that it works correctly with queries that have, say, `[` in them
- You do not need `(` and `)` around `expression` as this capturing group is not used anywhere later.